LIBMTP PANIC: Cannot open iconv() converters to/from UCS-2! Too old stdlibc, glibc and libiconv
I'm getting this error when I try some mtp commands.

LIBMTP PANIC: Cannot open iconv() converters to/from UCS-2! Too old stdlibc, glibc and libiconv?

I already checked my stdlibc.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; the starting point at understanding the issue is knowing what you're actually using & you've not specified. We're thus limited in what help we can provide.   At a guess from the little you provided; you're using the 5th from latest release.

This question is similar to: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not post pictures of text. Whenever possible always cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures can not be sorted or searched.
